# Scrapy AJAX send request to get response of generated HTML

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to crawl data from sites like [this](https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/Products/Singles/Exodus/Survival-of-the-Fittest).

To show all offers manually the "Show More Results" button at the bottom of the page has to be clicked until all offers are displayed. Upon clicking it an AJAX request is sent to the server which in response to this event shows more HTML (which I want to scrape).

The request copy URL looks like this:

```
https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/AjaxAction
```

but I don't want to leave the starting URL but instead just load more. The response also doesn't provide JSON or HTML and always looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ajaxResponse><rows>PGRpdiBpZ...</rows><newPage>1</newPage></ajaxResponse>
```

Other answers to similar questions usually got a JSON as the response or straight up HTML or recommended using Beautiful Soup but I am concerned about crawling speed as well.

How could I load the missing HTML and get the data in an efficient way?

Comment: you are going to have to use scrapy selenium or something like it.  You could extract the contents from the javascript in the `onclick` attribute and create a ajax request using that as the payload but then the response is still gzip encoded and you still wouldn't have access to the extra pages rendered after the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below example with `selenium, bs4 and pandas` is working smoothly where I have to use Javascript execution to click and complete the `show more result`.

**Example:**

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)

url = 'https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/Products/Singles/Exodus/Survival-of-the-Fittest'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

lst=[]
while True:

    soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
    for card in soup.select('[class="d-flex has-content-centered mr-1"] > a'):
        lst.append({'name': card.text})
 
    try:     
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="loadMore"]/button/span[2]'))
        pos= driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="loadMore"]/button/span[2]').click()
        
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        break

df=pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                 name
0               Lugones
1              odaJoana
2        Arcana-Trieste
3        Arcana-Trieste
4              Impavido
..                  ...
145              yoeril
146  JacobMartinNielsen
147               Artia
148               Nanau
149           magictuga

[150 rows x 1 columns]
```